# How do I change window theme in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, unity, themes

I don't know how I did it, but now I'm stuck with this same window theme!
Whichever theme I change to, the window theme will stick and only the background colour of the window title will change.

Here I changed from Ambience Blue Theme to Zukini Theme but only the background colour of the windows title change from blue to greenish, the rest is still the same.

EDIT:
Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I'm using Unity not Gnome3.

UPDATE: I tried to change with gconf-editor but it has failed to change the windows theme.

1.Window Theme selected in gconf-editor

[image]

2.Window Theme shown in gnome-tweak-tool

[image]

Comment: what are u using gnome-shell or unity?

Comment: my bad I didn't see the images.

Comment: I'm using Unity.

Comment: sorry looking at shell extension I assumed u r using gnome-shell as it was not mentioned :) anyways its been a while since I used Unity but I guess I had same issue, the theme was changed once I restarted / logoff-login if you have already tried it then I'm not much of a help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming u have user-theme extension installed.

1. U need to switch ON user-theme extension itself

[image]

2. Once u switch it ON then logoff and login or `Alt+F2 r`.
3. U should be able to see following menu:
   [image]

If you don't have user-theme extension installed itself then I advise you to follow: https://extensions.gnome.org/ or I had used http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html

Here are few themes: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/satyas-gnome-shell-gtk-themes-ppa.html

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/4-beautiful-gnome-32-compatible-gtk.html

Comment: Nice post, but I think the OP is using unity.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: yup looking at shell extensions in image I assumed gnome-shell (OP didn't mention it first) and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

first thing to notice is : both unity and gnome shell are SHELLS on top of gnome 3.
so if you are using unity , you are still using gnome 3.

now, wisemonkey's answer is correct. you need to use the same tool in unity and gnome shell, which is `gnome tweak` tool.if you don't have it installed, then search for it in the software center and install it.
it looks like this

[image]

now, if you are using unity you have to change the gtk+ theme and the window theme to your liking.

if this is not working, for some reason. try to go and open the gconf-editor.

hit `alt+f2` and type `gconf-editor`. you will get this type of a window.
[image]

then navigate to `desktop > gnome > shell> windows`.    and change manually the theme there to another one. then log out and in, or reboot.

Comment: I realized it after my post, but the real problem here is the window theme won't change even if I change it to another. If you clicked the links in my first post you will see the problem I stated.

Comment: it won't change even after reboot? anyway i did update my answer, adding another way you can try. let me know if something changes.

Comment: [Window Theme selected in gconf-editor](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/859/screenshotat20111210095.png/),
[Window Them shown in gnome-tweak-tool](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/52/screenshotat20111210095.png/),
[gnome-tweak-tool shell extension page shows nothing](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/404/screenshotat20111210095.png/)

Comment: strange thing. if you are running unity, there will be no extensions, it is only for gnome shell. update the question itself with all the new info and pics plz.

Comment: I tried to change window theme with gconf-editor and restarted but the window theme is still the same. It seems like my system is messed up. :(

Comment: i see. update the question with the new photos and gconf try failed.that would get you better chance of solving it. :) good luck

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'm not in a hurry. I hope I find a way to change though, otherwise I might have to reinstall the OS which I would not like to do at the moment.