# How to install GTK2-notif2 theme?

Tags: gtk

Here is the link: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=18886&foo=6

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 is based on Gnome 3, which means it uses GTK 3 and the theme you want to apply is GTK 2. This means that even if you do apply it will only affect GTK 2 apps and not GTK 3 apps, which will create a major rajor theme inconsistency.
I suggest you use a GTK 3 theme. You can find a lot of themes here:

- http://gnome-shell.deviantart.com/gallery/29380653

Or you can add the following PPAs:

- https://launchpad.net/~kokoto-java/+archive/omgubuntu-stuff
- https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/themes
- https://launchpad.net/~satyajit-happy/+archive/themes

If you don't know how to use PPAs please read this:
[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) and if you don't know how to install themes manually in Ubuntu 11.10 read this: [How to change GTK+ theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93278/how-to-change-gtk-theme)

Comment: Thanks for all the info! maybe I'll try to make a sun sparc theme for gtk3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gnome Shell, you can't, Gnome Shell is GTK3, this theme is GTK2 only and would not render correctly if at all.

If you are using Unity, this is a duplicate post:
[How do I change window theme in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86036/how-do-i-change-window-theme-in-11-10)

You should be able to use the gtk2 theme in Unity.

edit: perhaps I am wrong though, as it would seem unity uses gtk3 as well.

Comment: Both Unity and Gnome-Shell are built on top of Gnome 3 and therefore they use GTK 3 themes and not GTK 2 ones :)